# Bubble Sort Algorithm in Javascript

Tags: javascript, bubble-sort

I have this Bubble Sort algorithm here

```
let bubbleSort = (array) => {
  for (let j=0;j<array.length;j++) {
    for (let i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
      if(array[i] > array[i+1]) {
      let temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[i+1];
      array[i+1] = temp;
      }
     }
    }
   return array;
  }
```

I understand how it works, but I don't understand what the if statement means:

```
      let temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[i+1];
      array[i+1] = temp;
```

Edit:
I can't mark all answers as solved, but they helped me. Thank you!

Comment: Store this item in a temp var, assign the next item to this item, assign the temp var to the next item... I other words: replace the current item with the next item and the next item with the current item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The three lines swap the elements indexed by `i` and `i+1`.

You can **not** just write

```js
array[i] = array[i+1];
array[i+1] = array[i];
```

to swap the elements because in this version, after executing the first line, the original value of `array[i]` is lost, as it has been overwritten with the value `array[i+1]`.

To fix this problem, the value `array[i]` can be stored in a temporary variable (called `temp` here) such that it can later be assigned to `array[i+1]`.

Answer (score 1):

It is **swapping** the values of the current and next element inside the array.

The problem of something like this

```
   1. array[i] = array[i+1];
   2. array[i+1] = array[i]
```

is that in the first assignment you overwrite the regular value of array[i] with array[i+1] so that you would assign the same value of array[i+1] in the second line, therefore you use the temp variable to store the orginal value of array[i] to have this value after the assignment in line 1

```
  1 let temp = array[i];
  2 array[i] = array[i+1];
  3 array[i+1] = temp;
```

In line one you basically store the orignial value of array[i] to later on reassgign array[i+1] with it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place a new value at a position in an array, the old value at that position will be overwritten.

```
const arr = [0, 1, 3, 2]
```

We'll use this array as an example. If I want to swap the values at `arr[2]` and `arr[3]`, I could start by setting `arr[2] = arr[3]` resulting in the following. You'll notice that the value `3` is now missing!

```
 const arr = [0, 1, 2, 2]
```

This is why you create a `temp` variable. To temporarily store the value that will be overwritten. Here's an example with the index 2:

```
 // array = [0, 1, 3, 2]
 let temp = array[2];      
 // temp = 3
 // array = [0, 1, 3, 2]
 array[2] = array[2+1];
 // temp = 3
 // array = [0, 1, 2, 2]
 array[2+1] = temp;
 // array = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```